# Which expression is more correct, "He worries the baby about falling" or "the baby worries him about falling"?

Tags: sentence-usage

I just read this in a book (*In Cold Blood*):

> It's true the children do keep me busy...Donnie has learned to open the door and climb on the chairs & other furniture & **he worries me constantly about falling**.

I just have an odd feeling of the bold-faced words above. I have learned "worry about ...", I would tend to write the sentence as "I constantly worry him about falling".

To confirm. I consulted my dictionaries and found there is such collocation as "worry one(self) about/over...". So "he worries me constantly about falling" may be correct.

But is "I constantly worry him about falling" also correct?

Comment: It is the speaker who is doing the worrying, not the baby, so it is *he [Donnie] who worries **him** [the speaker] about falling*

Comment: *"I constantly worries him about falling"* is not grammatical. Instead, *I always worry about baby falling.* may fit.

Comment: *"I constantly worry him about falling"* is possible. I supposed that it could be said by an elderly person, where *him* could refer to someone who cares him.

Comment: I made a mistake. It should be "I constantly worry him about falling". I have edited the OP.

Comment: The author is creating a character here who is a sloppy writer or speaker, and possibly the user of a dialect. It's good to read literature as you learn English, but watch out for authors' portrayals of nonstandard language. Don't try to learn two-point perspective from a Cubist painting. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given it's [Truman Capote](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truman_Capote), I hesitate to say the phrasing is "incorrect" - but it's certainly "non-standard". Most people would say...

> *...and **I** worry constantly **about him** falling*.

OP's rephrasing *"I constantly worry him about falling"* is unlikely English. In the original, *to worry = to be concerned [about something]*, but *to worry [someone] = to **nag** [someone]* - a completely different sense.

---

The problem with Capote's version (the clumsy sequence his fictitious letter-writer uses, anyway) is that...

> 1: *He worries me constantly about falling.*
>    has superficially the same structure as, for example,...
>    2: *He worries me constantly about wanting to go to the circus.* [probably **him/his** "wanting"]
>    or
>    3: *He worries me constantly about drinking.* [probably **me/my** "drinking"]

Logically it's not likely that Donnie constantly *worries/pesters/nags* his mother because he wants to fall and she won't let him (sense #2), or because he's concerned that *she* might fall (sense #3). But given that *worry* can be used with those senses, it's obviously better to make the meaning absolutely clear.

Answer (score 1):

"Worry" is one of those verbs -- like "burn" -- that change in sense between the transitive and the intransitive.

> *The stick burns.*

The stick is on fire.

> *I burn the stick.*

The stick is on fire (due to an action of mine).

If *Donnie worries*, he feels the emotion.  If *Donnie worries me*, I feel the emotion. If *I worry him about falling*, I cause him to feel fear of falling, though it's unclear who would be falling. If *I worry about him falling* then I feel a fear of him falling.